# What is the Crocro and Friends app on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, system-apps

What is the Crocro and Friends app on the Samsung Galaxy S20?
I didn't install it, so I take it to be a pre-installed Android app.

Comment: [Samsung Community explains](https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-a/app-croco-and-friends/td-p/9594196)

Comment: App names can because of localization very different. It is better to use an app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csdroid.pkg which displays the app package name to search for the app.